# Python/ Selenium is not sending tilde character (~) to the input field

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to use Python/ Selenium/ Webdriver to automatically fill an input field in my Chrome webpage. However, I am not able to use "send_keys" to fill out the tilde character.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import os
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://mywebpageaddress")

browser.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys('charles~18')
```

But the "~" tilde is not appearing on the field.

It is filled just as "charles18" instead of "charles~18"

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Does the form field have javascript that limits the input to alphanumeric characters only?

Comment: No, it does not. It is possible to write "charles~18" manually through the browser interface.

Comment: Did you try using u'charles~18' , i.e. explicitly specify the unicode-ness of the string?

Comment: I've just tried using u'charles~18' and it still not working.. :/

Comment: Try this: `browser.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys('charles{~}18')
`

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML please?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation you can call multiple time **send_keys** method.

Try this.
1. split url by ~
2. send every fragmentation one by one.
3. only for ~ just send its unicode '\ue07E'

However this is not specify anywhere. but 7E is unicode for ~
special key mapping for selenium is [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html). Hope this help.

Java doc for selenium key is [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html)

Comment: I know that this question is about Phyton, but I had exactly the same issue on .NET Core. Sending unicode did not help, so I had to use javascript on the browser directly (as @hiren sudgested in other comment). For anyone interested:

public static void JsSetValue(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, string text)
        {
            var jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1];", element, text);
        }