# Selenium is not sending tilde character (~) to the input field

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I'm working on creating an application that gets a url from an excel sheet, but it has a tilde ('~') in the URL. This character does not copy itself when I copy it to an input field with selenium.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797295/python-selenium-is-not-sending-tilde-character-to-the-input-field) post from last year but there nobody can solved the problem. So hopefully someone will know the answer how :)

Thanks in advance!

```
#Fill in Discription
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="description"]').send_keys(Description)
```

Comment: What do you mean "there nobody can solved the problem"? Did you try the answer there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it on this way..

Description.replace('~','\u223C')

This works for me :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a representation of what our friend @Mithun Mandal said in the other post (It's in C#, shouldn't be too hard to convert to python, considering it's selenium).

```
string url = "www.test~dummy.com";
foreach (string x in url.Split('~'))
{
    element.SendKeys(x);
    element.SendKeys("\u223C");
}
element.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace); //this is used to erase the wrong tilde typed at the end of the URL
```

[image: Test]

Worked here.